# Delete duplicate records by leaving the min row in the table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table where duplicate rows exist and should be deleted leave one of the duplicate rows

The emp table has a unique constraint which includes name, age, sex

The following query works fine

```
    SELECT MIN(emp_no)
    FROM emp
    GROUP BY name, age, sex
    HAVING COUNT(1) > 1 INTO @emp_duplicate_ids;

    DELETE FROM emp 
    WHERE emp_no NOT IN(@emp_duplicate_ids);
```

Is there is any other short way or best method to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this (in test DB NOT production)

```
DELETE e FROM emp e 
JOIN (SELECT MIN(emp_no) AS emp_no FROM emp GROUP BY name, age, sex) f
ON e.name=f.name and e.age =f.age and e.sex=f.sex and e.emp_no <> f.emp_no
```

Comment: Can you please check the query, it is not working as expected? throws error: Unknown column 'f.emp_no' in 'on clause'

Comment: Edited the solution, do try it again.

Comment: same error and i am using MySQL database...please check the query in sqlfiddle.com whether it works for you..

Comment: It works, and I have similar query on my own to clear duplicated entries as well. can you try again with the updated solution.

Comment: This will delete all the records. You should add the condition e.name=f.name and e.age =f.age and e.sex=f.sex to join statement